# Anyone using Python for embedded projects?

Tags: python, embedded

My company is using Python for a relatively simple embedded project.  Is anyone else out there using Python on embedded platforms?  Overall it's working well for us, quick to develop apps, quick to debug.  I like the overall "conciseness" of the language.

The only real problem I have in day to day work is that the lack of static checking vs a regular compiler can cause problems to be thrown at run-time, e.g. a simple accidental cat of a string and an int in a print statement can bring the whole application down.

Answer (score 16):

We use python in quite a lot of [embedded boards with ARM processors](http://www.embeddedarm.com/products/arm-sbc.php) and 16 MB of RAM (running linux).

It works really well and is really easy to make custom code quickly - one of the strong points of python.

As for reliability of the code - we try to have 100% test coverage.  Writing tests with python is very quick and it gives you a wonderful feeling of confidence.  We use [twisted trial](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedTrial) to run the tests and report on coverage, but there are many other tools available.

In my experience python + tests is more reliable and much quicker to write than any other alternatives.

The only downsides for embedded work is that sometimes python can be slow and sometimes it uses a lot of memory (relatively speaking).  This hasn't causes us a show stopping problem yet, and python is quite easy to profile for both speed and memory if it becomes a problem.

[pychecker](http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/) is a very useful too also which will catch quite a lot of common errors.

Answer (score 10):

BTW, see this blog post: "[Type inference for Python](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1519)" for an interesting discussion of type inference and static typing, including links to some Guido van Rossum blog posts describing adding optional static typing to Python.

I agree with [Bruce Eckel](http://www.mindview.net/WebLog/log-0025) that one is better off practicing "strong testing" than relying on strong typing.  I think that applies equally well to embedded development.

Answer (score 9):

Personally, I've worked on some of the software that runs in the device used by [BusRadio](http://www.busradio.com/).  It's an example of an embedded project built on [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/) and Python.  The device is an embedded [XScale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XScale) processor running a [debian-derived](http://www.debian.org/) distribution, so it might not meet certain definitions of "embedded", but it is pretty dang small: it fits into the dashboard of a school bus.

There were some interesting issues with using Python with large libraries - the interpreter can take quite a while to start up and load all the code for Twisted on a really slow chip, and some things needed special-case optimizations.  However, at no point was the dynamic nature of Python a problem.  The software in question certainly wasn't perfect, but at least when using Twisted, a simple programming error will not "bring the whole application down".  A traceback will get logged, and processing continues.

So, if you're in an embedded environment sufficiently unconstrained that you can use Python in the first place, it's no different than developing "regular" programs (games, desktop applications, web apps).  You don't need static typing there, and you don't need it here either.

Comment: I'd stress how adequate is to use Twisted in this scenario.

Answer (score 8):

At my previous employer I had wanted to spend some time playing with building embedded systems in [tinypy](http://www.tinypy.org/), which is a "minimalist implementation of Python in 64k of code".  (But I never got to it and I no longer have time.)

Answer (score 8):

[Telit](http://www.telit.com/) makes [GSM/GPRS modem modules](http://www.telit.com/cellular/) that include an [embedded Python interpreter](http://www.telit.com/fileadmin/user_upload/products/Downloads/3G/Telit_Easy_Script_Python_r18.pdf).

I haven't tried them myself, so I don't know how the Python interpreter compares or differs from a PC implementation, such as which included modules, RAM and ROM memory limits, execution speed, etc.

However, as user foresightyj pointed out in a comment, it appears that they use Python 1.5.x, which is a truly ancient version, and so I would have trouble taking them seriously. Python developers would not enjoy downgrading to such an ancient version without so many modern Python features. I would be concerned about security issues with such an old version.

Comment: It is a nice way to code, but there are some performance issues when you try to do more on that platform. The good part is that the platform is not expensive, which is very important. See my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943919/efficient-string-to-hex-function

Comment: I used GM862-GPS modules from Telit. The Python is of verison 1.5.2 if I remember correctly. However, the speed is not all that great. There is no support for interrupts, signals or threads so your program has to feature a super loop. Thus, it is only good for small projects. As the OP pointed out that, because Python has no static type checking, it can crash due to some typos or wrong types. What I did is to put everything inside a big try except block and print out exceptions to the serial port or even a TCP socket so I know what happens.

Answer (score 7):

I've been working on microwave telecommunication equipments based on old and slow powerpc and 16Mb of RAM.

I've been able to port the Python 2.6.1 interpreter on VxWorks, in order to have the command line interpreter available directly from the target shell, or to execute python scripts uploaded to the target flash.

We used those scripts to perform autotest on the target or execute diagnostic procedures.
Here some details on the whole procedure: [HOW TO: Port Python to VxWorks](http://www.gsalcazar.altervista.org/tools/how-to-port-python-to-vxworks/)

Answer (score 4):

> The only real problem I have in day to
>   day work is that the last of static
>   checking vs a regular compiler can
>   cause problems to be thrown at
>   run-time, e.g. a simple accidental cat
>   of a string and an int in a print
>   statement can bring the whole
>   application down.

Unit tests are your only safety against these things.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, Python is often used as a 'support language' while you need to write some kind of tests - i.e. I was involved in a project, which (Python based) test framework code base was (is?) almost as big as that of the main product. 
Python 'agents' works on QNX, VxWorks - and most problems we have, was to port properly threading and network related parts of our code.

It might be worth to take a look [OpenMoko project](http://www.openmoko.org/) a lot of embedded development in Python is done there.

Things to watch-out:
- support for Python/C extension module might behave quite strangely depending on platform/OS
- most of embedded platforms offers quite out-dated versions of Python
- finally you will find out that there is a difference between 'proper' embedded software in which every bit counts, and 'modern' embedded software that is performed on >412Mhz XScale CPUs with more thatn 128MB, and then Python just don't match the hardware that you would like to target :(

Answer (score 3):

We use Python here at the university for embedded applications based on the Gumstix hardware platform.  Although more capable than traditional embedded systems, we find the mix of small formfactor, low (ish) power consumption and the ease in transferring code between development on desktop machines and the target hardware invaluable.

Python is also a great language to teach the students, and with the Gumstix its great they can get code working on a low power system, rather than the headache and heartbreak that comes with using dedicated languages such as NesC.

Answer (score 3):

My team wrote an embedded software made out of C++ and Python. We decided to write basic classes and heavy computational routines in C++. We wrote logic in Python. Boost libraries as glue. Using boost is never easy, but the results is excellent. Fast and easy to modify. Using python to represent the custom needings,  we are able to satisfy customers' needings realtime, changing the code using injection technics. Something really exciting! (ok, I'm a geek ;)

We started prototyping in python but we suddenly realized that it was clearly too slow. So we decided to structure the program in different computational layers, in order to reach the speed requirements. C++ was the best solution.

In order to use python and c++ together we had to keep a strict control on typing.

Answer (score 3):

I worked for a company which used Python on an embedded product based around an Atmel AVR32 and running embedded Linux. The firmware was initially developed on a PC (due to lack of a working hardware prototype), then later moved to the embedded hardware running on the cross-compiled Python interpreter.

The ability to debug and modify source code "live" on the device was a big plus during development, and saved a lot of time. The big disadvantages were speed and memory usage of the Python interpreter.

Following the first release of production firmware we ported critical sections of code over to C/C++. The porting effort was quite straightforward and resulted in an improvement of several orders of magnitude on speed-critical code (as you would expect).

Incidently most of the design and production testing code was written in Python, mainly running inside a test harness on a PC.

Comment: May I know how do you port over to C? Ctypes or python extension wrapper?

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, Python has been traditionally used in desktop environments more than in the embedded field. There are two reasons, related to the fact that Python is interpreted:

- C/C++ languages have higher performance than Python (and this is important in embedded systems with a slow microcontroller)
- C/C++ languages have more deterministic response times (and this is important in real-time embedded systems controlling something).

Of course, as embedded systems will become faster and time-to-market shorter, Python will be more adopted in the embedded sector.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Python server (using [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)) and some helper scripts running under XP Embedded, and it's been working great.

Answer (score 2):

## Recent developments

- [MicroPython](http://micropython.org/) is a lean and fast implementation of the Python 3 programming language that is optimised to run on a microcontroller.
- The European Space Agency (ESA) is [funding further development of MicroPython](http://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=744). It is doing so to assess the suitability of the language for space-based applications, in particular for payloads.
- **WiPy 1.0 & 2.0, LoPy & SiPy** are wireless MicroPython platforms sold by [Pycom](https://www.pycom.io/).

[image: The WiPy 1.0]

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the [EVE Online](http://www.eve-online.com/) client a showpiece of real-time, high-performance Python?

Comment: EVE Online use stackless another implementation of python language, is different then cpython and they don't have any embedded application, and all universe in EVE is on one big cluster.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using a Gatetel GT-HE910 series module which embeds the Telit modem including 3G, GPS, AD, IO and Python 2.7. This is used for a remote data aquisition application. Python is fairy slow on these modules but we only need an update every 15 minutes or in an alarm condition so they work well.

http://www.gatetel.com/#!gt-series/cscb

Answer (score -5):

> Blockquote
>   The only real problem I have in day to day work is that the last of static checking vs a regular compiler can cause problems to be thrown at run-time, e.g. a simple accidental cat of a string and an int in a print statement can bring the whole application down

To me it is a huge deal. Problems you could find at compile time and fix the problem now have to rely at run time. Not knowing the data type and having to write additional function just to check the datatype is hassle. There is no need to do that in C. How would you declare 'volatile' in python?

> Blockquote
>   The only downsides for embedded work is that sometimes python can be slow and sometimes it uses a lot of memory (relatively speaking). This hasn't causes us a show stopping problem yet, and python is quite easy to profile for both speed and memory if it becomes a problem.

This is also huge. For Embedded sytems or RTOS time constraint is very important.

Python is not necessary quick to code. It really depends what language you are comfortable with. Honestly it takes me 1 day to write function and unnecessary object orientation stuff  which I can do in 2 hours in C. 
Testing is so inconvenient  I have to write the code, py_compile, copy pyc in the target then run the program, then python quits complaining variable not defined or type cast error or some petty thing like that.

My suggestion is C toolchain is available for any target. C is fast, hardware oriented,challenging and fun. Stick with C for Embedded systems. No need to install configure silly python packages just to run it.