# Anyone using Scheme/LISP for embedded projects?

Tags: embedded, lisp, scheme

This question is maybe somehow inspired with [Anyone using Python for embedded projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240996/anyone-using-python-for-embedded-projects); so anyone using some Scheme version or Common Lisp (like ECL) for free/oss/commercial projects?

Personally, I used (and still using) TinyScheme for personal projects where some embedded language is needed, mostly due extremely easy embedding (sorry Python lovers, been there and that is quite painful, especially after I learned from TinyScheme how things *can* be simple).

Answer (score 3):

The most prominent project I remember hearing about is (Gambit) [Scheme on the iPhone](http://jlongster.com/software/iphone/scheme-iphone-example/). It was shut down by the user agreement for a while but I suppose with the new one, this kind of development is allowed again.

I don't see it on the page any more, but I remember a related blog post about interactive development on the iPhone using Scheme. Very exciting.

Comment: The new agreement still won't allow any application where the end user can write code of their own for it. Interpreters are allowed, but on the condition that all scripts are part of the app itself, and can never be obtained at run time.

Comment: I don't think Denis was asking how to interpret user code, although I'm not certain. 'Embedded' is kind of ambiguous here.

Comment: Gambit in its current state does not generate code which is actually linkable or importable into an existing Xcode project.
It appears to assume a much older toolchain, and a very old version of Xcode. LLVM support is experimental and, AFAIK, very immature.