# Efficient string to hex function

Tags: python, hex

I'm using an old version of python on an embedded platform ( [Python 1.5.2+ on Telit platform](http://www.telit.com/en/products/python/python-for-m2m-applications.php) ). The problem that I have is my function for converting a string to hex. It is very slow. Here is the function:

```
def StringToHexString(s):
    strHex=''

    for c in s:
        strHex = strHex + hexLoookup[ord(c)]

    return strHex
```

*hexLookup* is a lookup table (a python list) containing all the hex representation of each character.

I am willing to try everything (a more compact function, some language tricks I don't know about). To be more clear here are the benchmarks (resolution is 1 second on that platform):

N is the number of input characters to be converted to hex and the time is in seconds.

- N    | Time (seconds)
- 50   | 1
- 150  | 3
- 300  | 4
- 500  | 8
- 1000 | 15
- 1500 | 23
- 2000 | 31

Yes, I know, it is very slow... but if I could gain something like 1 or 2 seconds it would be a progress.

So any solution is welcomed, especially from people who know about python performance.

Thanks,

Iulian

PS1: (after testing the suggestions offered - keeping the ord call):

```
def StringToHexString(s):
    hexList=[]
    hexListAppend=hexList.append

    for c in s:
        hexListAppend(hexLoookup[ord(c)])

    return ''.join(hexList)
```

With this function I obtained the following times: 1/2/3/5/12/19/27 (which is **clearly** better)

PS2 (can't explain but it's blazingly fast) A BIG thank you Sven Marnach for the idea !!!:

```
def StringToHexString(s):
    return ''.join( map(lambda param:hexLoookup[param], map(ord,s) ) )
```

Times:1/1/2/3/6/10/12

Any other ideas/explanations are welcome!

Comment: We're on an embedded platform and performance is a concern, and we're using Python? An older version, no less, presumably because recent ones aren't supported? Somehow doesn't sound like the right tool for the job to me...

Comment: @Karl Knechtel, python is the only way to code on that platform. Starting from the webpage I have given you can clearly see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Try also caching `ord` to avoid that look-up as well (looking up built-ins is even slower than globals).  Another alternative avoiding the repeated look-up of `ord` is `for c in map(ord, s): ...`.

Comment: @Sven Marnach Your idea rocks. I put everything in one line and it seems to work like a charm. Don't really know why but it seems to be fast fast fast (almost 3 times faster). Thanks!

Comment: In a modern Python, you'd use a list comprehension; it avoids the overhead of a `for` loop – I guess on your hardware that's pretty expensive. `map()` is the next best thing... One more thing is to try `hexLookup.__getitem__` instead of the lambda (hopefully 1.5 has that).

Comment: @PetrViktorin unfortunatelly no __getitem__ doesn't exist, but it's good practice in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def StringToHexString(s):
    return ''.join( map(lambda param:hexLoookup[param], map(ord,s) ) )
```

Seems like this is the fastest! Thank you Sven Marnach!

Answer (score 5):

Make your hexLoookup a dictionary indexed by the characters themselves, so you don't have to call `ord` each time.

Also, don't concatenate to build strings – that used to be slow. Use `join` on a list instead.

```
from string import join
def StringToHexString(s):
    strHex = []

    for c in s:
        strHex.append(hexLoookup[c])

    return join(strHex, '')
```

Comment: First test (keeping the ord call):
1/2/3/5/12/19/27 which seems to be a fair improvement! Will continue tests!

Comment: check my latest test and if you can explain, please do cause all I can say is: I'm amazed. Is python working faster if less code is involved? (at least on that ancient version - 1.5.2+ )

Answer (score 2):

Building on [Petr Viktorin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943919/efficient-string-to-hex-function/7943954#7943954), you could further improve the performance by avoiding global vairable and attribute look-ups in favour of local variable look-ups.  Local variables are optimized to avoid a dictionary look-up on each access.  (They haven't always been, by I just double-checked this optimization was already in place in 1.5.2, released in 1999.)

```
from string import join
def StringToHexString(s):
    strHex = []
    strHexappend = strHex.append
    _hexLookup = hexLoookup
    for c in s:
        strHexappend(_hexLoookup[c])
    return join(strHex, '')
```

Comment: using a dictionary makes things slower

Comment: look at my latest test (PS2) and if you know a better alternative I am open to suggestions. You are free to explain what is happening there 'cause I really can't explain why that piece of code works THAT fast compared to the one before (PS1).

Answer (score 1):

Constantly reassigning and adding strings together using the `+` operator is very slow. I guess that Python 1.5.2 isn't yet optimizing for this. So using [`string.join()`](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.2p2/lib/module-string.html#l2h-547) would be preferable.

Try

```
import string
def StringToHexString(s):
    listhex = []
    for c in s:
        listhex.append(hexLookup[ord(c)])
    return string.join(listhex, '')
```

and see if that is any faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
from string import join

def StringToHexString(s):
    charlist = []

    for c in s:
        charlist.append(hexLoookup[ord(c)])

    return join(charlist, '')
```

Each string addition takes time proportional to the length of the string so, while `join` will also take time proportional to the length of the entire string, but *you only have to do it once*.

You could also make `hexLookup` a `dict` mapping characters to hex values, so you don't have to call `ord` for every character. It's a micro-optimization, so probably won't be significant.

Comment: actually adding a dictionary makes things slower in my tests

Comment: @IulianŞerbănoiu Not really surprising. You're trading a constant-time speedup of removing the `ord` for the constant time slowdown of a hash and lookup vs. array indexing.

Comment: Check my latest test (PS2) in my post. If you're willing to explain why are those HUGE differences in performance I would be glad to know. Is python better when less code is written? Thanks a lot!