# Optimizing the size of embedded Python interpreter

Tags: python, embedded

I spent the last 3 hours trying to find out if it possible to disable or to build Python without the interactive mode or how can I get the size of the python executable smaller for linux.

As you can guess it's for an embedded device and after the cross compilation Python is approximately 1MB big and that is too much for me.

Now the questions:

Are there possibilities to shrink the Python executable? Maybe to disable the interactive mode (starting Python programms on the command line).

I looked for the configure options and tried some of them but it doesn't produce any change  for my executable.

I compile it with optimized options from gcc and it's already stripped.

Comment: See this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240996/anyone-using-python-for-embedded-projects?rq=1) for running in 16MB RAM

Comment: i have read it but the problem is that tinypy wasn't updated since 2008! And for tinypy it not possible to use all libraries or not easy to use! Too much work for each library. Impossible goal that python had a size of less than 500kb

Comment: Many years ago I was at a company that used embedded hardware and, after trying many different interpreters, we decided on an embedded Forth. The executables were smaller than the native binary, I kid you not.

Comment: Yeah, tinypy is a reimplementation of part of Python, not a real embedded Python. I've seen ads for someone who makes a plug-and-play embedded Python system that only uses 8MB of NVRAM leaving 3MB for scripts and data and over 1MB for RAM, but that implies it's still nearly 4MB…

Comment: What is your target platform? (The more details the better, but at least the CPU.)

Comment: I use the OpenWRT Enviroment and the target platform is running with an ARM CPU

Answer (score 6):

If you reallly want to shrink python, you can have a look at those project :

http://code.google.com/p/python-on-a-chip/

as said on the site :

> Python-on-a-Chip (p14p) is a project to develop a reduced
>   Python virtual machine (codenamed PyMite) that runs a significant
>   subset of the Python language on microcontrollers without an OS. The
>   other parts of p14p are the device drivers, high-level libraries and
>   other tools. Please join the python-on-a-chip google group to discuss
>   this project.

This may be a little lower level than expected, but it really is shrinked :

Features of the PyMite VM:

- Requires roughly 55 KB program memory
- Initializes in 4KB RAM; print "hello world" needs 5KB; 8KB is the minimum recommended RAM.
- Supports integers, floats, tuples, lists, dicts, functions, modules, classes, generators, decorators and closures
- Supports 25 of 29 keywords and 89 of 112 bytecodes from Python 2.6

You could get interesting ideas from this project.

Beware that you only get the virtual machine, ie. you can run pyc files, not py. (pyc files are cross platform, though. And much smaller than py files)

In fact, if you really target smallest python, you need to disable parts of the library, but maybe also the compiler itself.

This site might have interesting pointers also : http://www.awaretek.com/pymo.html

Comment: +1. Very interesting. It looks like a clean-room Python-like language rather than a hack of CPython (mark-sweep GC, stackless, no C extensions, etc.). I think I suggested that would be too much work for the OP's project to do from scratch, but to build on PyMite might be a perfectly reasonable project. It probably depends on how much of the stdlib functionality the OP needs.

Answer (score 3):

There may be ways you can cram it down a little more just by configuring, but not much more.

Also, the actual interactive-mode code is pretty trivial, so I doubt you're going to save much there.

I'm sure there are more substantial features you're not using that you could hack out of the interpreter to get the size down. For example, you can probably throw out a big chunk of the parser and compiler and just deal with nothing but bytecode. The problem is that the only way to do that is to hack the interpreter source. (And it's not the most beautiful code in the world, so you're going to have to dedicate a good amount of time to learning your way around.) And you'll have to know what features you can actually hack out.

The only other real alternative would be to write a smaller interpreter for a Python-like language—e.g., by picking up the tinypy project. But from your comments, it doesn't sound as if "Python-like" is sufficient for you unless it's very close.

Well, I suppose there's one more alternative: Hack up a different, nicer Python implementation than CPython. The problem is that Jython and IronPython aren't native code (although maybe you can use a JVM->native compiler, or possibly cram enough of Jython into a J2ME JVM?), and PyPy really isn't ready for prime time on embedded systems. (Can you wait a couple years?) So, you're probably stuck with CPython.

Comment: +1 with the above statements. Having Python fit into 1Mb is already quite an achievement. If space is so tight on the embedded device, I would consider smaller alternatives, like lua (claimed to fit in less than 500kb)

Comment: Thx you guys for the fast help and of course for the correction of my english! I think we let Pyhton on this size now and perhaps build it in our future hardware when we have more flash space. THX to all

Comment: PyPy will very likely never be ready to use in such constricted environments. The added abstraction definitely adds to the size and the JIT compiler embedded in the executable does not help.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this question in late 2018.  At this point in time the most popular tiny python -- and the one designed specifically for restricted platforms and embedded devices -- is [MicroPython](https://micropython.org/) which is popular for things like microcontrollers.